# Can you partially specialize a partial specialization of a class in c++

Tags: c++11, templates

I have a question about the hierarchy for partial specialization of templates with `c++-11`. I have been reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization but can't quite get my head around how the particulars work with methods of partially specialized template classes.

I have a class that looks like

```
template <typename T, int N, int D, bool b>
class ClassA {
public:
T foo( std::array<T,N> const& x );
T bar( std::array<T,D> const& y );
protected:
/* some member variables */
std::array<T,N> var1;
std::array<T,D> var2;
};
```

If `b` is false, then I have a partial specialization for all `T,N,D`

```
template <typename T, int N, int D>
class ClassA<T,N,D,false> {
public:
T foo( std::array<T,N> const& x ) const { /* stuff for all T,N,D */ };
T bar( std::array<T,D> const& y ) const { /* stuff for all T,N,D */ };
};
```

If `b=true`, then I have a partial specialization for `foo` that works for all T,N,D, but not for `bar`.

```
template <typename T, int N, int D>
class ClassA<T,N,D,true> {
public:
T foo( std::array<T,N> const& x ) const { /* stuff that works for all T,N,D */ };
// Can't define bar yet, don't have sufficient information on D.
// T bar( std::array<T,D> const& y ) const { /* Don't know this yet */ };
};
```

but for `bar`, I have partial specializations for `D = 1,2,3,4` (which are the only values of D I want to support).

```
template <typename T, int N>
class ClassA<T,N,1,true> {
public:
// Don't want to define foo again. want to use the definition from the b = true specialization
// T foo( std::array<T,N> const& x ) const { /* This was defined in the one parameter specialization */ };
T bar( std::array<T,1> const& y ) const { /* stuff that works for all T,N */ };
};
```

My question is: Will the specialization for `D=1` have the specialization for `b = true`? Do specializations apply nestedly? I.e. a partial specialization on 2 parameters can use missing function definitions that were defined in the specialization on one parameter? Or do I need to copy paste the definition of foo into the four 2 parameter specializations?

For details, all of these methods rely on using member variables of the `ClassA`, else I would break them out into plain functions.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassA<T,N,1,true>` is more specialized than `ClassA<T,N,D,true>` so this is a new class to define from scratch. That's why i've looked myself at the new language features called if constexpr and requires(concepts): it will change the way you see things

```
template <typename T, int N, int D, bool b>
class ClassA
{
public:
T foo( std::array<T,N> const& x )
{
    if constexpr ( !b )
        // do something
    else
        // do something else (only the active statement will generate errors)
}

template <class=void>// allow the requirement below
requires !b || (D >= 1 && D <= 4)// this line can completely remove bar if you need
T bar( std::array<T,D> const& y )
{
    if constexpr ( !b )// no run time checking
        // do something
    else
        if constexpr ( D == 1 )
            // do something
        else if ( D == 2 )// also constexpr
            // do something
        else if ( D == 3 )
            // do something
        else if ( D == 4 )
            // do something
        else
            // non specialized code or
            static_assert(false);// compile time error if you want to get ride of the requires
}

protected:
/* some member variables */
std::array<T,N> var1;
std::array<T,D> var2;

};
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use constexpr on conditional branches like that! Does that mean that the unreachable branches of that logic will just be compiled away for a given instantiation? 

The reason I ask is that we are optimizing this chunk of code to try reduce the number of conditionals. This code gets called an enormous number of times and makes up the largest chunk of our run time. If it's possible to just move the conditionals onto templates (with a little bit of work we can know them at compile time, at least for the worst offenders), then this would help a lot!

Comment: you are right, the inactive statement will not annoy you anymore :)

Comment: Sad thing is that I am constrained to live in the c++11 world, so I don't think I can do that. It's one really neat trick though! Definitely would be nice to be c++17

Comment: You can also take a look at std::enable_if but be aware of what you want in advance since this feature doesn't cover everything seamlessly. std::conditional can be helpful too.